# Wireless USB - D-Link DWA-125, constant authentication required. Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: 10.10, wireless, authentication

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop clean install on a hard drive.
I then plugged in my D-Link DWA-125, and it immediately picked up my home network. So I click connect, and after a while, it asks for authentication, I put in the correct details (I know they're correct for a fact since the other PC's (Windows) connect just fine to the network).

Thing is, it doesn't connect. It just has that wireless connection icon going up and down, (I think it's trying to connect?), and then after a while, it asks for authentication again. It's never making the connection, it's like it's in an authentication loop.

What is the problem? The fact that the device even works and picks up the network is not a sign of no driver installed?

I read on here went to my wireless USB, the DWA-125. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsDlink

And it says:

Download, compile and install the native driver from source. Reportedly does not support WPA2. Installing Windows drivers (via ndiswrapper) reportedly fails.
2011-04-18 (Ubuntu 10.04)

That is for Ubuntu 10.04, and I'm obviously running 10.10.

My wireless router is a D-Link as well and the security types are as follows:

```
Network Authentication: Shared
WEP Encryption: Enabled
Wep Encryption Strength: 128
And the key.
```

Comment: Post your fix as the answer and later accpet it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. Had to manually edit the connection and change the WEP Index and Authentication under the "Wireless Security" tab. I completely missed it. It's working great now.